# Экспорт данных в excel из html

Tags: php, html, excel

Есть html файл с данными. В нём есть как просто input'ы, так и таблицы, кнопки. Новые строки и таблицы генерируются с помощью javascript'а. Т.е. их кол-во всегда разное. У всех уникальный `id`, который тоже генерируется по типу: `"a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2" ...`

Стоит еще отметить, что есть несколько div'ов. В первом вводится название, во втором данные, а в третьем эти данные рассчитываются по формулам и вставляются в таблицы. Соответственно, на каждом из этапов два других div'а скрыты.

Как можно эти данные экспортировать в excel? Например используя phpexcel.

Comment: На javascript написать функцию, которая будет собирать все данные в один объект и посылать его какому-нибудь php скрипту на сервер.  Далее, написать этот скрипт, который принимает эти данные и использует phpexcel для создания файла.

Comment: @AleksG "собирать все данные в один объект" например всё в одну таблицу?

Comment: Нет, в один javascript object, скорее всего, с массивом - или просто в массив.

Comment: @AleksG а если у меня форматирование разное в каждом div'е, то получится ли его сохранить при переносе? дело даже не в цвете\шрифте, а именно в расположении данных. что бы эти данные потом можно было нормально прочитать.

Comment: Так или иначе все данные из html надо передать на сервер, с цветами ли, с форматированием ли. phpexcel должен знать как форматировать документ. Из html-кода он это не поймет.